# Why it is not possible to have such a graph of a function?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Suppose we have function $f(x)$ that is continious and it has first and second order derivatives and its table likes the following.
$\ \begin{array}{ c|c|c|}
 & x< 0 & x >0\\
\hline
f' & - & +\\
f'' & - & -
\end{array}$

Question is " Why it is not possible to have such a graph of a function? "

- My attempts: I thought that if I have the following table $\ \begin{array}{ c|c|c|}
   & x< 0 & x >0\\
  \hline
  f' & - & +\\
  f'' & + & +
  \end{array}$ then I can say that function can be $f(x)=x^2$. But for above, again I thought that maybe function can be $-x^2$ which satisfies the conditions of table which is **totally wrong**. So, can you help me to figure out the question? Gracias

Comment: If $f'' < 0$ everywhere, as you show in the first table, then $f'$ is strictly decreasing. So there is no way for $f'$ to go from negative to positive. That is it.

Comment: How can you obtain $f'$ is strictly decreasing from $f'' < 0$

Comment: I don't even know how to answer that. But I'll say this: breath, open your math book, focus, read. It usually works.

Comment: @FuatRay Consider the tangent line interpretation of the derivative and what the second derivative tells you about those tangent lines. Use that geometric idea to structure your argument.

Comment: Is this related about the following If $f^{n+1}$ is always negative then $f^{n}$ is decreasing. Because I know that if $f'(x)$ is negative in some interval then $f(x)$ is decreasing in same interval.